# Revoking right for user to DROP table

Tags: sql, postgresql, privileges

I am a big fan of PostgreSQL but can't figure out one aspects of it's built in user management.

My problem is that I have set up pgAdmin and will have some non-developers manually update data in some specific tables. For this reason I have created a new user called "admin" and are looking to restrict this users rights.

I have tried to delete all rights for the user with the following query (from another user):

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM admin;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public FROM admin;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public FROM admin;
```

The above did lead to the following error when I wrote a simple SELECT statement from the user admin on a table called "crap": `ERROR:  permission denied for relation crap`.

But what I was able to do with the user admin which by now shouldn't have any rights was the following: `DROP TABLE crap;` which worked!?

I am really surprised by this. This user is not a Postgres superuser. How can I remove this right to drop tables for a specific user?

Comment: From the [Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droptable.html): ```Only the table owner, the schema owner, and superuser can drop a table.``` So whose table is it?

Comment: Thx for your comment. `SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename = 'crap';` shows that the user in this example "admin" is not the owner.

Answer (score -1):

You're one level off in hierarchy for the permissions.

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM SCHEMA public FROM <role_name>;
```

You were affecting permissions within the table. You must also go one level up to the schema as well to protect create/drop access. You may also want to revoke access at the database level as well to protect the schema.

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM DATABASE <database_name> FROM <role_name>;
```

You could also simply remove the user. Alternatively you could simply disable that user's ability to login.

```
ALTER ROLE <role_name> SET NOLOGIN;
```

If these don't work for you, you can go down a somewhat more complicated route and make an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html) that watches for DROP TABLE events, compares against the role, and either allows it to continue or aborts the transaction.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION no_admin_drop()
  RETURNS event_trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  IF CURRENT_USER = 'admin'::regrole THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'command is disabled';
  END IF;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER no_admin_drop ON sql_drop
   EXECUTE FUNCTION no_admin_drop();
```

Comment: Thx! I need the user to be able to SELECT but not DROP. So removing the user is not an option. I tried revoking priveleges as you mentioned (should be ON and not FROM though I guess): 
```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE prices_prod FROM admin;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM admin;
```
But this user "admin" was still able to drop the table.. Any thoughts?

Comment: I added another option: an event trigger

Comment: Much appreciated! Event trigger could indeed achieve what I want to do. I saw something in another Stackoverflow-thread and tried to go down that route. Unfortunately I'm running my PSQL instance on Google Cloud SQL where they don't allow the user to have the superuser role which is needed for these kind of system triggers.